# I have to parse hindi text from API using volley

Tags: java, android, json, api

I want to parse a JSON response using volley, JSON response contain Hindi data also, so how can I get that Hindi data in my test view

I had just parse JSON array using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` and just fetch data by using `getString()` method.

```
 final String URL = "http://[DomainName]/getSubCategory";
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
            dialog.cancel();
           Log.d("1234","responce array  "+response.toString());

           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
           JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_cat_list");
           Log.d("1324","responce array  "+array.toString());

          for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject main_recipes = array.getJSONObject(i);

          SubCatPojo pojo = new SubCatPojo();

          pojo.setCatId(main_recipes.getString("id"));

          pojo.setCatName(main_recipes.getString("name"));

          pojo.setCatImage(main_recipes.getString("image"));

           arrayList.add(pojo);
           }

          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      },
      new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               dialog.cancel();
               Toast.makeText(Listing.this, "error in network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
     }) {
      @Override
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("p_id", catId);
                    return map;
                }
            };

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
```

But in logcat, I got this response

```
{ "sub_cat_list":[{"id":6,"name":"\u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0917\u0923\u0947\u0936 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/shree-ganesh-ji.png"},{"id":7,"name":"\u0913\u092e \u091c\u092f \u091c\u0917\u0926\u0940\u0936 \u0939\u0930\u0947 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/vishnu-ji.png"},{"id":8,"name":"\u0926\u0941\u0930\u094d\u0917\u093e \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/durga_ma.png"},{"id":9,"name":"\u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940 \u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0932\u0915\u094d\u0937\u094d\u092e\u0940 \u092e\u093e\u0924\u093e  ","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/laxmi_ma.png"},{"id":10,"name":"\u0936\u093f\u0935 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/shiv.png"},{"id":11,"name":"\u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0939\u0928\u0941\u092e\u093e\u0928 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/hanuman_ji.png"},{"id":12,"name":"\u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0938\u0930\u0938\u094d\u0935\u0924\u0940 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/banner_img\/sarswati_maa.png"},{"id":13,"name":"\u0915\u0941\u0902\u091c \u092c\u093f\u0939\u093e\u0930\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/\/banner_img\/Kunj_Bihari.png"},{"id":14,"name":"\u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0936\u0928\u093f \u0926\u0947\u0935 \u0915\u0940 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940","img_url":"http:\/\/poojavidhi.webepower.biz\/banner_img\/shani_dev.png"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) :

```
import android.text.Html;

String base = "\u0936\u094d\u0930\u0940 \u0917\u0923\u0947\u0936 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940";
String decoded = Html.fromHtml(base,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString();
```

> Decoded: श्री गणेश आरती

Now, I didn't really dig further with the [flags you can use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#constants_2) but this one seems to work. If you stumble upon issues, you should definitely try other flags.

Answer (score 0):

**Using core java, Only you have to convert the unicode characters to UTF-8.**

First, get the value for key 'name' while iterating over the object and then try to apply below code, and the again set the value corresponding to the key 'name'.

I'm just showing the way to convert, a part of your sample string.

```
            String string ="\u0913\u092e \u091c\u092f \u091c\u0917\u0926\u0940\u0936 \u0939\u0930\u0947 \u0906\u0930\u0924\u0940";
            byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

            string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(string);
```

It will give you output like : 'ओम जय जगदीश हरे आरती' |